# I can't access my LVM partition after RAID recovery

Tags: linux, hard-drive, lvm, mdadm, raid-5

I need help after an accident with my RAID 5.

I recreated it with:

```
mdadm --verbose --create /dev/md2 --level=5 --chunk=64 --raid-devices=4 /dev/sdb4 /dev/sda4 /dev/sdd4 missing
```

My array seems to be OK:

```
md0 : active raid5 sdc4[3] sdd4[2] sda4[1] sdb4[0]
      5855756544 blocks super 1.2 level 5, 64k chunk, algorithm 2 [4/4] [UUUU]`
```

```
mdadm --detail /dev/md0
/dev/md0:
        Version : 1.2
  Creation Time : Sun Jun  7 10:03:07 2015
     Raid Level : raid5
     Array Size : 5855756544 (5584.48 GiB 5996.29 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 1951918848 (1861.49 GiB 1998.76 GB)
   Raid Devices : 4
  Total Devices : 4
    Persistence : Superblock is persistent

    Update Time : Sun Jun  7 10:03:07 2015
          State : clean
 Active Devices : 4
Working Devices : 4
 Failed Devices : 0
  Spare Devices : 0

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 64K

           Name : technique-mint:0  (local to host technique-mint)
           UUID : 1131eb64:74bcfd5c:1fe7e2b8:4e819428
         Events : 0

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       8       20        0      active sync   /dev/sdb4
       1       8        4        1      active sync   /dev/sda4
       2       8       52        2      active sync   /dev/sdd4
       3       8       36        3      active sync   /dev/sdc4
```

But I can't see my LVM partition at `/dev/vg0`

`pvscan` returns nothing...

I tried all drives order possibilities with this script: https://raid.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Permute_array.pl 
But nothing ...